# Change simgle key with mod key behaviour in openbox and x11

Tags: x11, keyboard, openbox

I'm trying to change de behaviour of pressing key AltGR + z. Now, when I press this combination of keys, character « is written, but I would like to write < symbol.

I executed this command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 52 = z Z z Z less guillemotleft'
```

This command works fine, but changes aren't permanent. How could I make it permanent, or how could I change the behaviour of AltGR (mod1) + z?

Note:
 less: <
 guillemotleft: «

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your command in `~/.config/openbox/autostart`.

This file is executed by openbox on startup (for more information on openbox autostart see the [Openbox Wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart))

Comment: I tried to do that. It works most of time, but when working some time with the computer, setup is replaced (I don't conditions to happen that)